# Sql-Server Unique Constraint but with NON-unique data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, unique-constraint

I've inherited this database which has a table defined as such :

```
CREATE TABLE home_tickets(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    identifier nvarchar(45) NOT NULL,
    start_date_time datetime NOT NULL,
    revised bit NOT NULL,
    agency_code nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    archived tinyint NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK__home_tic__3213E83F236943A5 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id ASC) WITH (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON PRIMARY,

    CONSTRAINT UQ__home_tic__969168722645B050 UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (identifier ASC) WITH (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON PRIMARY
) ON PRIMARY
```

However when I select from the table given an `identifier` I am getting multiple rows returned.

```
select * from home_tickets where identifier = 'TI54815780';


id      identifier  start_date_time         revised archived
415044  TI54815780  2013-10-24 00:00:00.000 0       0
652845  TI54815780  2014-10-24 00:00:00.000 0       0
171642  TI54815780  2012-10-24 00:00:00.000 0       0
945275  TI54815780  2015-10-24 00:00:00.000 1       0
1220327 TI54815780  2016-10-24 00:00:00.000 1       0
```

Why would this happen with a unique constraint on `identifier` ?

Comment: Did you check the actual definition of the table, as it is now? Or you got this CREATE TABLE statement from a script that was initially used to create the table? There is a column mismatch between the code and the output (column `agency_code` missing). Could be that the table was altered in between? (column removed, index disabled or dropped)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - this is the DDL i have generated as of this morning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the underlying constraint index is disabled.  You can verify this with:

```
SELECT is_disabled
FROM sys.indexes
WHERE
    object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'home_tickets')
    AND name = N'UQ__home_tic__969168722645B050';
```

After the bad values are remediated, rebuild the index to enable the constraint:

```
ALTER INDEX UQ__home_tic__969168722645B050 ON home_tickets REBUILD;
```

Comment: yes - this returns 1